# Search For an Object in Complex Object as below

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a JSON data as below

```
{
    "id": "0001",
    "fieldName": "sample1",
    "fieldValue" "0001",
    "subList": [
        {
            "id": 1001,
            "fieldName": "Sample Child 1",
            "fieldValue": "1001",
            "subList": []
        },{
            "id": 1002,
            "fieldName": "Sample Child 2",
            "fieldValue": "1002",
            "subList": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I wanna search for an object where ever in the data

Comment: not valid object for a start

Comment: what should be searched, what returned?

Comment: if i search with {id: "0001"} i have to get full object if i search with 1001 i have to get `Sample Child Obj'

Comment: So what have you tried? Just recursively traverse the `subList`s.

Comment: I have tried but not sure about the logic, not getting how o write it

Comment: Do you only want to search the IDs? Is the structure always the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the search object contains only one property:

```js
function search(s, o) {
    var k = Object.keys(s)[0], r;
    if (o[k] === s[k]) {
        return o;
    }
    o.subList.some(function (a) {
        r = search(s, a);
        return r;
    });
    return r;
}

var obj = { "id": "0001", "fieldName": "sample1", "fieldValue": "0001", "subList": [{ "id": 1001, "fieldName": "Sample Child 1", "fieldValue": "1001", "subList": [] }, { "id": 1002, "fieldName": "Sample Child 2", "fieldValue": "1002", "subList": [] }] };

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(search({ id: '0001' }, obj), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(search({ id: 1001 }, obj), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```